# cleaning dataset in r - add value to NA cell

Tags: r

I have a dataframe (see below) and I am having some troubles when I try to clean it.

Row dataset looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame(
    id = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2),
    company_name = c("aaa", NA, NA, "ccc", NA),
    directors = c(NA, "xxx", "bbb", NA, "ooo"),
    year = c(2001, 2001, 2001, 2002, 2002)
)

> df
  id company_name directors year
1  1          aaa      <NA> 2001
2  1         <NA>       xxx 2001
3  1         <NA>       bbb 2001
4  2          ccc      <NA> 2002
5  2         <NA>       ooo 2002
```

and I need it to look like this:

```
df_fixed <- data.frame(
    id = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2),
    company_name = c("aaa", "aaa", "aaa", "ccc", "ccc"),
    directors = c(NA, "xxx", "bbb", NA, "ooo"),
    year = c(2001, 2001, 2001, 2002, 2002)
)

> df_fixed
  id company_name directors year
1  1          aaa      <NA> 2001
2  1          aaa       xxx 2001
3  1          aaa       bbb 2001
4  2          ccc      <NA> 2002
5  2          ccc       ooo 2002
```

Then I can delete all data without director names.

I think it can be done by some matching. I tried to store a unique list of ids to select company names, but it doesn't work well. I greatly appreciate it if you have any suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `fill` from `tidyr`

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    fill(company_name)
```

-output

```
 id company_name directors year
1  1          aaa      <NA> 2001
2  1          aaa       xxx 2001
3  1          aaa       bbb 2001
4  2          ccc      <NA> 2002
5  2          ccc       ooo 2002
```

---

Or if it is grouped by 'id', 'year'

```
df %>%
    group_by(id, year) %>%
    fill(company_name, .direction = 'downup') %>%
    ungroup
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not fully sure from your question if that was what you were asking, but if you want to fill all NA in the column V1 of a dataframe df with a value "val", you can do it with

```
df$V1[is.na(df$V1)] <- "val"
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to do this. One really easy one is to use the `na.locf` function from the `zoo` package.

```
library(zoo)
df$company_name <- na.locf(df$company_name)
> df
  id company_name directors year
1  1          aaa      <NA> 2001
2  1         <NA>       xxx 2001
3  1         <NA>       bbb 2001
4  2          ccc      <NA> 2002
5  2         <NA>       ooo 2002
```

A base R way that assumes that the map of ID and company_name is what dictates the values is to merge the unique ID/company name set back into the data frame.

```
company_ids <- unique(df[!is.na(df$company_name), c("id", "company_name")])
df_new <- merge(
    x = df[c("id", "directors", "year")],
    y = company_ids
)
> df_new
  id directors year company_name
1  1      <NA> 2001          aaa
2  1       xxx 2001          aaa
3  1       bbb 2001          aaa
4  2      <NA> 2002          ccc
5  2       ooo 2002          ccc
```

This is a blunt approach using a `for` loop (often frowned upon but not actually that big of a deal).

```
val <- NA
for (x in seq_len(nrow(df))) {
    if (!is.na(df[x, "company_name"])) {
        val <- df[x, "company_name"]
    } else {
        df[x, "company_name"] <- val
    }
}
> df
  id company_name directors year
1  1          aaa      <NA> 2001
2  1          aaa       xxx 2001
3  1          aaa       bbb 2001
4  2          ccc      <NA> 2002
5  2          ccc       ooo 2002
```